# unterminated string literal while display arabic text using html() function

Tags: javascript, php

I used to display the alert messages in my login widget using html() as like as

```
$("#error-msg1").html("<php _e('please Enter Email','domain'); ?>");
```

It works correctly. But after translating the arabic text( فضلاً يجب إدخال عنوان بريد إلكتروني) for the english text "please enter email", It displays the unterminated string literal error. How to solve that??

Comment: You might need  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type"  CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=iso-8859-6"> to be set .

Comment: its worked @chandresh_cool

Comment: Cool enjoy and Happy coding.